# From convex set to convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, definition, intuition

The **definition** of a *convex set* is geometrically intuitive. But the definition of *convex function* doesn't seem so intuitive: $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex if given $x,y\in S$ the line segment joining $x,y$ is in $S$.

Let $f$ be a real valued function from an open interval $I$. Consider the graph of $f$ in plane: set theoretically it is
$$\{(x,f(x))\,|\, x\in I\}.$$
For any $a,b\in I$, consider the line joining $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$. Then one of the following happens:

1. The line lies above the graph of $f$.
2. The line lies below the graph of $f$.
3. None of these hold.

> **Q.** Suppose you know the definition of *convex set* and let $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which does not satisfy (3). This means $f$ satisfies (1) or (2). What is *intuition way* to define function to be convex or concave?

For example, in Wikipedia, it  says that *a function is convex if graph above $f$ is convex*. But if we are trying to give intuitive definition of convex function based on convex set, according to convexity of region above $f$ or below $f$, what is intuitive way to decide one of them?

---

Since $f$ is satisfying (1) or (2), so the words *convex function* and *concave function* are reserved for it; we can assign any word to any case without intuition. But, considering definition of *convex set* can we get intuition to define convex function? Note that almost everyone knows geometric explanation of the standard definition of convex function.

Comment: What is the reason to downvote? (I think there should be option for reasoning downvote!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [article of wikipedia about convex functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) the relation between the two concepts is stated in this way:

> A function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ is convex if its [epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) (the set of points on or above the graph of the function) is a convex set.

where the epigraph of a function as the above is defined formally as follow:

$$\operatorname{epi}(f):=\left\{(x,\mu)\in\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R: \mu\ge f(x)\right\}\tag1$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm refer Boris T. Polyak in his book 'INTRODUCTION TO OPTIMIZATION', page 8.

**Definition of convex function**

A scalar function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb R^n$ is said to be *convex* if

$$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)$$

for any $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ and $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$.

**Theorem**

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. $f$ is a convex function if and only if $H_{\gamma}=\{(x,\gamma)|\gamma \geq f(x)\}$ is a convex set.

Now, look this theorem who is so powerful.

**Theorem**

A function $f$ is convex if and only if $\nabla^2f(x)\geq 0$.

$\nabla^2f(x)$ are Hessian matrix and $\nabla^2f(x)\geq 0$ refer nonnegative definite.

*Example*

Let $g(x,y) = x^2-xy+y^2$.

$$\implies \nabla g(x,y) = (2x-y,-x+2y)$$
Then
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2g(x,y) = 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
2 & -1\\
-1 & 2
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\end{equation}

$$\implies \nabla^2g(x,y)\geq 0,\forall x,y\in \mathbb R$$

$$\therefore g(x,y) \text{ is a convex function}$$

Note that if $\nabla^2f(x)$ are not a constant matrix but is nonnegative definite you can not say $f(x)$ are a convex function because this needs to be true on all variables of the function by definition of convex function.