# Show the feasible set of convex functions is convex.

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, convex-optimization, alternative-proof

### Problem Statement

Let $g_{1},\dots, g_{M}$ be convex functions and let  $b_{1},\dots, b_{M}$ be real numbers. Show that $F:=  \{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{d} : g_{i}(\boldsymbol{x}) \leq b_{i}, $ for all $i = 1,\dots , M \}$ is a convex set.

### Attempted Proof

We endeavour to prove that a given set, $F:=  \{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{d} : g_{i}(\boldsymbol{x}) \leq b_{i} \forall i = 1,\dots , M \}$ is convex. Where $\{g_{i}\}_{i=1}^{M}$ represents convex functions and  $\{b_{i}\}_{i=1}^{M}$ represents real integers.

We know, from the definition of a convex set that the feasible set  $F:=  \{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{d} : g_{i}(\boldsymbol{x}) \leq b_{i}, $ for all $i = 1,\dots , M \}$ is convex  on the condition that all the functions  $\{g_{i}\}_{i=1}^{M}$ are convex.

**Explanation**

I am trying to show that the set is convex by taking two points x and y which are in the set and show that for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$, the point $\lambda \boldsymbol{x} + (1-\lambda) \boldsymbol{y} $ is also in the set. Where a point will be in the set if it satisfies all the constraints.

The problem is I am struggling to take my first attempted at a proof and use a more mathematically method to prove this by taking two points in the set as described above. I would like to use the definition of a convex function ,i.e. a convex function $f$ , is one that satisfies for $0 \leq \lambda \leq1$,
    \begin{eqnarray*}
   f(\lambda \boldsymbol{x} +(1-\lambda)\boldsymbol{y} ) \leq \lambda f(\boldsymbol{x}) + (1-\lambda)f(\boldsymbol{y}) \text{.} 
\end{eqnarray*} 
 I have found similar questions with regards to the sum or quotient of convex functions online but I have not come across a proof of this with a good solution so far. Could someone please show me how they would formulate this proof.

This question was similar:
[From convex set to convex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780597/from-convex-set-to-convex-function)

Comment: Label two points in $F$ differently, set up the convex combination, then see if you can show it satisfies the inequality given in the definition of $F$. You will have to use that $\lambda +(1-\lambda)=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_M$ be convex functions from $\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_M \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show that $F := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : g_i(x) \leq b_i, \, i \in 1, 2, \ldots, M\}$ is convex.

To start, suppose that $x_1 \in F$ and $x_2 \in F$ are arbitrary points in $F$ and that $t \in (0,1)$. We want to show that $x_3 = tx_1 + (1-t)x_2 \in F$.

First, consider an arbitrary $i \in 1,2,\ldots, M$. By definition of the convexity of $g_i$, we know that $g_i(x_3) = g_i(tx_1 + (1-t) x_2) \leq tg_i(x_1) + (1-t)g_i(x_2)$. By definition of $F$, we know that $tg_i(x_1) + (1-t)g_i(x_2) \leq tb_i + (1-t)b_i = b_i$. Thus we have that $g_i(x_3) \leq b_i$, and we can repeat this argument for all $i$. Thus $x_3 \in F$. Hence $F$ is a convex set.